# Qt - drawing after receiving signal

Tags: qt, drawing, signals

I have a simple application, that consists of one line edit, where user writes an answer and a confirmation button. If the answer was correct, I'd like to draw a simple figure (green / red circle for example). I have three source files - main, form (here I connect the signal from button with answer from lineedit and determine if answer is correct) and figureWidget, where i'd like to draw my figure. My problem is, that I can't find out how to connect the signal from "form" with my figureWidget (especially what with what and where :-) ) Any hints?
file form.cpp:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include "ui_untitled.h"
#include "Form.h"
#include "figureWidget.h"

Form::Form(QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) : QWidget ( parent,f ) {
   ui.setupUi(this);

connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(buttonPressed()), this, SLOT(checkAnswer()))
 //this checks if answer is correct after pushing button
connect(this,SIGNAL(correctness(QString)),ui.figureWidget, SLOT(drawFigure(QString)));
  //I expect signal from this class (here I check the answer), and draw the circle in figureWidget
}

void Form::checkAnswer() {
 if (ui.lineEdit == "1") emit correctness(QString("right");
  else emit correctness(QString("false") 
  }
```

then I have the figureWidget.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>
#include "figureWidget.h"
figureWidget::figureWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) {
}

figureWidget::~figureWidget() {
}

void figureWidget::drawFigure(QString newVal) {
 if (newVal == correctVal) 
     update();
}

void figureWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* ) {
   QPainter painter(this);
   painter.setPen(QRgb(0x0000ff00));
   painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 10, 10);
}
```

in debug i get:
No such slot QWidget::drawFigure(QString) in ...

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/signalsandslots.html - I'm sorry but your question is very vague. You connect a signal to a slot, and that's it. If you've got code that doesn't work as you expect it to, please show that code so that people can help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was hoping that someone could figure out what I mean (maybe common problem). Anyway, I added the code

Comment: Where is `checkAnswer`? Where to you emit the `correctness` signal?

Comment: checkAnswer is in form.cpp (where are the connects). This slot also emits the correctness signal

Comment: I don't understand your problem then.  Are the slots not being called?

Comment: Well, when I try to build, I get : Unresolved external symbol : form::drawFigure(class QString) etc... I can see, that problem is, that I have drawFigure in figureWidget, not in form, but how can I change it?

Comment: If your code doesn't actually build, **say so in the question**!. Please don't post build errors in comments, update your question. And make sure the relevant code is there too.

Comment: (firstly I could build, but in debug I find out, that connection wasn't established, secondly I changed it to updated code, which ends up with link error)

Comment: Maybe you should also post the code from form.cpp so we can get a better understanding of your problem.

Also your building error could be that the drawFigure(QString) slot should be a method of the figureWidget class, and, based in the code you shared, it isn't there.

Comment: gosh i'm sorry, I pasted old code, it should be ok now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(correctness(QString)),this, SLOT(drawFigure(QString)));


void Form::drawFigure(QString val)
{
   ui->figureWidget->drawFigure(val);
}
```

But how could figureWidget appears after 'ui->'??? You cannot draw it on the UI statically.